# function as method argument in jquery without writing the entire function definition

Tags: jquery, function, arguments

From what i understand, in jquery, when a method requires a function as an argument you can't just invoke a predefined function like this:

```
$('#target').click(myFunction());
```

...because "myFunction()" will be parsed and replaced with the value returned by the function...which is no longer a function.You have to put the entire function definition, in an anonymous function:

```
$('#target').click(function() {
   alert('Handler for .click() called.');
});
```

...so, is there any way of just invoking the function where it's required as an argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You understand correctly. It is true not only in jQuery, this is how JavaScript works. When a function is needed as an argument, then you have to give a function as an argument, and not the result of its invocation. You can use this:

```
$('#target').click(myFunction);
```

but for alert you need an anonymous function because you are passing an argument.

Comment: +1 Addendum: Functions in JavaScript are *just objects* that can be applied [read: invoked] with the `()` operator. That is, `fn()` evaluates the expression `fn` to the function-object (say `fn` is `fn = function () { ... }` or `function fn () { ... }`) and then the `()` operator invokes the function-object and the value of the expression is the result of that invocation [read: what was `return`'ed]. Thus, without the `()` operator, the name of a function evaluates to the function-object itself. (This is a good bit different than how Java/C/C++/C# (or even Ruby) work but similar to Python.)

Comment: thanks...so you can't invoke it with arguments:    $('#target').click(myFunction(arg1, arg2));   ?

Comment: @bogdan You can -- but that passes the *result* of `myFunction(arg1, arg2)` as the value to `click` [see `()`]. This is case for a closure: `elm.click(function () { myFunction(arg1, arg2) })`, where `arg1` and `arg2` are free variables in the enclosing scope. Note that the function-object returned by `function () { ... }` is *not* evaluated (applied/invoked), but rather passed as the argument to `click` -- click will invoke the function-object passed in later when an event occurs and that (anonymous) function object invokes `myFunction` with the given variables (hopefully) bound in a closure.

Comment: @pst Thank you for the in depth explanation :)

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the result of the function, not the function itself.  Instead of:

```
click(myFunction());
```

use

```
click(myFunction);
```

Live [example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YVm8u/3/).